# Assigning pch symbols in plot

Tags: r, plot, pch

I have a plot of many omega values within which I want to highlight about 40 points among the many others. The plot argument I am using is:

```
plot( log( dog[ order( dog$gbm.dog ) , 8 ] ), 
     pch = ifelse( dog$refseq_mrna %in% dog_omegaplus$refseq_mrna, 2,
           ifelse( dog$refseq_mrna %in% dog_omegaminus$refseq_mrna, 12, "." ) ) )
```

I want to have one group of highlighted points to be triangles (`pch = 2`), the other group to be squares (`pch = 12`) and all other points dots ("."). The problem is that the plot this produces has digits where the `pch` symbols should be (specifically a "2" where there should be triangles and a "1" where there should be squares).

How do I designate the symbols correctly?

Comment: create a factor with you groups (`fac`) and a vector of symbols (`sym = c(2,12)` then you can use `col=sym[fac]` for coloring. For more sophisticated advice please provide reproducible code: http://tinyurl.com/reproducible-000

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem here is that using "." coerces the 2's and 12's to character values. I constructed a simple test case to see what was happening and whether I could find a numeric designation that would be satisfactory:

```
x <- 1:20

 ifelse(x < 5 , 2, ifelse(x > 15, 12, "."))
 [1] "2"  "2"  "2"  "2"  "."  "."  "."  "."  "."  "."  "."  "."  "."  "."  "."  "12" "12" "12" "12"
[20] "12"

# only return integers

plot(x, pch= ifelse(x < 5 , 2, ifelse(x > 15, 12, 20)))
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

The help page `?points` says that `pch=46` is the equivalent of `pch="."`, so if you change `"."` to `46` in your original code then everything will stay as a numeric vector and should give you what you want.